# What are the meanings of "devoted to" and "year of years" in the passage?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Even his artistic oeuvre, though sublime, is minute. Fewer than 20 finished works are generally attributed to da Vinci. He failed to complete some of his most important commissions such as the “Adoration of the Magi”. His ill-fated experimentation with materials ruined others, including “The Last Supper”. **Hence the paucity of exhibitions devoted to his art in what should be his year of years.** Florence is commemorating him with a show **devoted to** his master, Verrocchio.

https://www.economist.com/books-and-arts/2019/04/20/was-leonardo-the-supreme-genius-or-just-our-kind-of-guy

1.What is the meaning of "devoted to" in these two sentences?

2.What is the meaning of "year of years"?

3.What is the meaning of the whole sentence "Hence the paucity of exhibitions devoted to his art in what should be his year of years"? I just cannot recognise which word is its verb.

Thanks for answering.

Comment: An exhibition could described as being *devoted to* the art of Leonardo da Vinci if there was nothing else exhibited (i.e. the only things exhibited were artworks by LdV).

Comment: *Year of years* means a (very) special year, like the 500th anniversary of his death.

Comment: The whole sentence means that the reason why there aren't as many LdV exhibitions as you might expect in such a special year is that he didn't actually produce all that much artwork, and some of his most famous works were left unfinished and/or spoilt by his experimentation.

Comment: @Minty Thanks a lot. Understood. Could you tell me the subject, predicate and object of the sentence "Hence the paucity of exhibitions devoted to his art in what should be his year of years"? It seems that it is not a complete sentence but a noun with many modifiers.

Comment: There is no verb in the sentence. But its meaning is understood in context. Replace *hence* with *this explains* if you want a complete sentence.